# Checking for multiple conditions using "when" on single task in ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to evaluate multiple condition in ansible using when, here is my playbook:

```
- name: Check that the SSH Key exists
   local_action:
     module: stat
     path: "/home/{{ login_user.stdout }}/{{ ssh_key_location }}"
   register: sshkey_result

 - name: Generating a new SSH key for the current user it's not exists already
   local_action:
      module: user
      name: "{{ login_user.stdout }}"
      generate_ssh_key: yes 
      ssh_key_bits: 2048
   when: sshkey_result.rc == 1 and  ( github_username is undefined or github_username |lower == 'none' )
```

here is my var file for reference:

```
---
vpc_region: eu-west-1
key_name: my_github_key
ssh_key_location: .ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

When I try to execute this playbook, I am getting this error:

```
TASK: [test | Check that the SSH Key exists] **********************************
ok: [localhost -> 127.0.0.1]

 TASK: [test | Generating a new SSH key for the current user it's not exists already] ***
 fatal: [localhost] => error while evaluating conditional: sshkey_result.rc == 1 and  ( github_username is undefined or github_username |lower == 'none' )

        FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Can somebody point me out that how we can use multiple conditions with ansible on single task.

Thanks

Answer (score 92):

You can use like this.

```
when: condition1 == "condition1" or condition2 == "condition2"
```

Link to official docs: [The When Statement](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#basic-conditionals-with-when).

Also Please refer to this gist:
https://gist.github.com/marcusphi/6791404

Answer (score 37):

Adding to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1638814/nvartolomei answer, which will probably fix your error.

Strictly answering your question, I just want to point out that the `when:` statement is probably correct, but would look easier to read in multiline and still fulfill your logic:

```
when: 
  - sshkey_result.rc == 1
  - github_username is undefined or 
    github_username |lower == 'none'
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement

Answer (score 8):

You can use logical operators to combine conditions. When you have multiple conditions that all need to be true (that is, a logical and), you can specify them as a list:

```
tasks:
  - name: Shut down CentOS 6 systems
    ansible.builtin.command: /sbin/shutdown -t now
    when:
      - ansible_facts['distribution'] == "CentOS"
      - ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == "6"
```

Link to the doc : https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your conditional is in this part `sshkey_result.rc == 1`, because `sshkey_result` does not contain `rc` attribute and entire conditional fails.

If you want to check if file exists check `exists` attribute.

Here you can [read more about stat module and how to use it](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/stat_module.html).

Comment: As a followup to what @nvartolomei said, when you have a variable like `sshkey_result` I find it extremely useful to display its value immediately after its set while writing/debugging a playbook.  Adding in a `-debug: var=sshkey_result` task will show you that as he said, `rc` doesn't exist in this context, and it will also show you what properties of that variable *do* exist.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `default()` filter. Or just a shortcut `d()`

```
- name: Generating a new SSH key for the current user it's not exists already
  local_action:
    module: user
    name: "{{ login_user.stdout }}"
    generate_ssh_key: yes 
    ssh_key_bits: 2048
  when: 
    - sshkey_result.rc == 1
    - github_username | d('none') | lower == 'none'
```